# Trying to get a property of a none object on laravel relationship belongsTo and hasMany

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I get null when trying to get posts associated with the user.

Comment: try adding the local key and foreign key to your relationships. user(){return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id', 'id');}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$user->posts` isn't defined. add this to your user Model:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

perhaps you have to load the posts after creating user `$user->load('posts');`

Comment: Thankyou sir exchanged the methods in both Models it is now working thanks

Comment: I think the function names are just backwards in the classes. The User class should have a `posts` function, then Post class should have a `user` function.